# How to add a view to the StoryBoard to utilise within viewForHeaderInSection?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uistoryboard

The SectionView.xib will be just a padded label in size of a cell:

[image]

```
@interface SectionView : UITableViewHeaderFooterView
{ 
   @property(weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *newsCategoryTitle;
}
```

Then in `viewForHeaderInSection` I would set the label and return the view.

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    SectionView *header = (SectionView *) [[self tableView] dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier:@"SectionView"];

    header.backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, header.bounds.size.width, header.bounds.size.height)];

    NSString *title;
    [[header newsCategoryTitle] setText:title];
    return header;
}
```

Last but not least I would register the `sectionView.xib` with the viewCOntroller that holds the TableView.

Without Storyboard I would register the sectionView.xib in the ViewController like this:

```
[[self tableView] registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"SectionView" bundle:nil] forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier:@"SectionView"];
```

I have no idea how and if this can be done right away in the storyboard.

The new storyboard contains just a custom cell definition in the table, but I haven't found any way to add a section header view to the storyboard.

[image]

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: you mean that you want to add header/footer to the table view in storyboard?

Comment: No, I need to define a custom sectionView. This can be done if `- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView { }` is populated and its higher than 1.

Answer (score 1):

I was actually super close.

Instead of registering the nib in

```
-(instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
```

I had to register it in

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
```

Now it works perfectly.  I happy to accept a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

Make a custom cell from storyboard and use it as a viewForHeaderInSection.

```
-(UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"SectionHeader"; 
    UITableViewCell *headerView = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    return headerView;
}
```